# 'operator=' is deprecated: Use QDir::setPath() instead

Tags: c++, qt5

Simple program that opens a GUI, you click one button to set `curDir`, click another button to set `savDir`, and a third button does some C++ code similar to

```
ls -l curDir > savDir.txt
```

One of my Qt functions:

```
void dirList::on_savBut_clicked(){
    savDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
                this,"Save Location",QDir::homePath());
    savPath = savDir.absolutePath();
    ui->savText->setText(savPath);
}
```

On the `savDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(...` line I get a warning:

```
'operator=' is depreciated: Use QDir::setPath() instead
```

Could anyone give an example how I might incorporate `setPath()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply write

```
savPath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
            this,"Save Location",QDir::homePath());
```

Without using savDir.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `setPath` is just a drop in replacement instead of using assignment for when updating a `QDir` with a `QString` path.

```
savDir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
                this,"Save Location",QDir::homePath());
```

simply becomes

```
savDir.setPath(QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(
                this,"Save Location",QDir::homePath()));
```